Chatting @someone makes a notification?
If I chat @ someone, like, by including their name in my post, will they be notified in the StackExchange bar?  I have a commenter on one of my questions that I'd like to clarify in chat without extending the comment thread too long to work it out, but I can't see how to do that without at least adding another comment!?
Thanks!

I believe so, I have always been. However if that person hasn't been on the chat in a long time it might not show, so I'd be interested in an official source too. I'm wondering if this shouldn't be migrated to MSO, though, since it's pretty much applicable to the entire network.

Maybe.

To get another user's attention, mention them – type @ and then the first part of their name. Your mention will be highlit on their screen – @someone. This will happen even if they are in a different room. Note that you can only mention @someone who has been in the room at some point. If you need to invite someone to your room, do it from the user's chat profile page or from the user card that pops up when you click on their avatar in a chat room.

So if the person has been in the room, you can just @-mention them.  But if they haven't you can try inviting them.
But generally, unless you know that a person uses chat, it's probably better just to add one more comment to the post.  You can always flag a moderator later to clean up obsolete comments.

To clarify what you've said: It will give someone a notification if they've been in the room but aren't currently. In these cases it will come up on the notification bar.

@figlesquidge: Exactly correct.
